# check if jquery has been loaded, then load it if false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to check if jquery has been loaded (with javascript) then load it if it hasnt been loaded.

something like

```
if(!jQuery) {
    //load jquery file
}
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up! hopefully it won't actually ever have to be called. just trying to add a little bit of redundancy

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that the document has a `head` that it can append a script element to

Comment: @DanielLeCheminant good point on that. What if it was `( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ).appendChild( script );`

Comment: @Pawel I've seen some implementations insert the element before/after the first script tag, since you know there has to be one of those.

Comment: I believe appending a script tag to body works in all browsers.

Comment: So,  in conclusion; the safest method will be:  ( document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0] ).appendChild( script );   Since there will be at least an instance of script tag.

Answer (score 110):

Avoid using "if (!jQuery)" since IE will return the error: jQuery is 'undefined'

Instead use: if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

You'll also need to check if the JQuery has loaded after appending it to the header.  Otherwise you'll have to wait for the window.onload event, which is slower if the page has images.  Here's a sample script which checks if the JQuery file has loaded, since you won't have the convenience of being able to use $(document).ready(function...

http://neighborhood.org/core/sample/jquery/append-to-head.htm

Comment: What about `script.onload = function() { alert('jQuery loaded!');  }`? Would that work?

Answer (score 14):

Method 1:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
}
```

Method 2:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```

If jquery.js file is not loaded, we can force load it like so:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
  var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
  // Path to jquery.js file, eg. Google hosted version
  jq.src = '/path-to-your/jquery.min.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

This checks if jQuery is available or not, if not it will add one dynamically from path specified.

Ref: [Simulate an "include_once" for jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887735/simulate-an-include-once-for-jquery)

OR

include_once equivalent for js. Ref: https://raw.github.com/kvz/phpjs/master/functions/language/include_once.js

```
function include_once (filename) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Legaev Andrey
  // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   improved by: Michael White (http://getsprink.com)
  // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // -    depends on: include
  // %        note 1: Uses global: php_js to keep track of included files (though private static variable in namespaced version)
  // *     example 1: include_once('http://www.phpjs.org/js/phpjs/_supporters/pj_test_supportfile_2.js');
  // *     returns 1: true
  var cur_file = {};
  cur_file[this.window.location.href] = 1;

  // BEGIN STATIC
  try { // We can't try to access on window, since it might not exist in some environments, and if we use "this.window"
    //    we risk adding another copy if different window objects are associated with the namespaced object
    php_js_shared; // Will be private static variable in namespaced version or global in non-namespaced
    //   version since we wish to share this across all instances
  } catch (e) {
    php_js_shared = {};
  }
  // END STATIC
  if (!php_js_shared.includes) {
    php_js_shared.includes = cur_file;
  }
  if (!php_js_shared.includes[filename]) {
    if (this.include(filename)) {
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you may have a head appending it may not work in all browsers. This was the only method I found to work consistently.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');        
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't `document.write` *HIGHLY* frowned upon?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if jQuery is loaded or not by many ways such as:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {

    // jQuery IS NOT loaded, do stuff here.

}
```

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'function')
//or
if (typeof $== 'function')
```

```
if (jQuery) {
    // This will throw an error in STRICT MODE if jQuery is not loaded, so don't use if using strict mode
    alert("jquery is loaded");
} else {
    alert("Not loaded");
}
```

```
if( 'jQuery' in window ) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Now after checking if jQuery is not loaded, you can load jQuery like this:

> *Although this part has been answered by many in this post but still
>   answering for the sake of completeness of the code*

```
    // This part should be inside your IF condition when you do not find jQuery loaded
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I made an good solution what is tested on serval places.

https://github.com/CreativForm/Load-jQuery-if-it-is-not-already-loaded

CODE:

```
(function(url, position, callback){
    // default values
    url = url || 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js';
    position = position || 0;

    // Check is jQuery exists
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        // Initialize <head>
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        // Create <script> element
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        // Append URL
        script.src = url;
        // Append type
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        // Append script to <head>
        head.appendChild(script);
        // Move script on proper position
        head.insertBefore(script,head.childNodes[position]);

        script.onload = function(){
            if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback(jQuery);
            }
        };
    } else {
        if(typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback(jQuery);
        }
    }
}('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js', 5, function($){ 
    console.log($);
}));
```

At GitHub is better explanation but generaly this function you can add anywhere in your HTML code and you will initialize jquery if is not already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = ()=>{
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js";
        e.onload = function () {
            jQuery.noConflict();
            console.log('jQuery ' + jQuery.fn.jquery + ' injected.');
        };
        document.head.appendChild(e);
    } else {
        console.log('jQuery ' + jQuery.fn.jquery + '');
    }
};
f();
```

Comment: you have to add some comment on your code to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined'){
        document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using CDN for my project and as part of fallback handling, i was using below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                if ((typeof jQuery == 'undefined')) {
                    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Responsive/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));   
                }
</script>
```

Just to verify, i removed CDN reference and execute the code. Its broken and it's never entered into if loop as **typeof jQuery** is coming as **function** instead of undefined .

This is because of cached older version of jquery 1.6.1 which return **function** and break my code because i am using jquery 1.9.1. As i need exact version of jquery, i modified code as below,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            if ((typeof jQuery == 'undefined') || (jQuery.fn.jquery != "1.9.1")) {
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Responsive/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));   
            }
</script>
```