# How does LinkedIn know or keep track of where I embedded its widget?

Tags: javascript, html, api, widget, linkedin-api

When you try to integrate with LinkedIn's `Apply Now` button, you first sign up for an API key. The form asks you to enter the Javascript Domain API, which is the `Fully-qualified domain name of all pages that will call the JavaScript API with this key.` In return, it produces an API key and some HTML code for you which you can copy n paste to your web page and get started.

This is the code their wizard produced:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">

  api_key: 7a4ghb12agvda4552da

</script>

<script type="IN/Apply" 

data-companyname="Asd"
data-jobtitle="Software Developer"
data-joblocation="Istanbul"
data-email="abc@xyz.com">

</script>
```

Now, how does one keep track of where this script is embedded? I first entered `http://example.com` as the my Javascript Domain API. It turned out that I can only use this widget on the example.com domain.

What's inside `in.js` that tells LinkedIn where it is embedded?

The reason I'm asking is because I am also building a widget myself, and I want to make sure only the signed-up domains can use my widget.

**Edit:** As a bonus, what if I download `in.js`, remove the part where it does the domain check and include my own version of in.js in my page? How do they prevent that?

[A LinkedIn employee mentions that both client-side and server-side checks are done.](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/security-prevent-impersonations) But what kind of a check would that be? I am looking for some deep insight into the issue. How can I produce such a widget? On the client-side, how do you check the current page that hosts your .js file? And how do you get which domain is hosting the js file?
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get further details?

Answer (score 3):

The LinkedIn Javascript framework won't work if you make a local copy of in.js - the backend server (which in.'s calls) checks to make sure that the in.js is coming from the correct server as well as checking to make sure that the framework will only work on the specified domain(s).

This question was asked/answered here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/security-prevent-impersonations

Comment: Thanks Kirsten, but how exactly are these checks performed? How do they check and authorize my domain with client-side code? And how do they perform such a check server-side? Can you share your deeper insights on this matter please?

Answer (score 2):

`in.js` has a script which adds another script tag into the DOM. It passes the API key (probably as a GET parameter in the script's URL), then the server checks the HTTP referer (which is a standard HTTP header browsers send indicating the website which sent them to get that page) and checks if it matches the API key in the database.

A simpler version would contain something like this:

```
document.write('<script src="http://mysite.com/api.js?key="' + api_key + '></' + 'script>');
```

Then on the server, something like this pseudo-code:

```
var expectedDomain = queryTable('apikeys').equal('key', GET('key')).field('domain').run();
if (expectedDomain === parseDomain(http.referer)) {
    respond(myscript);
}
```

Comment: Are you certain this is the way they do it? What if a user uses a browser that doesn't send the Referer header? Or what if it's tweaked?

Comment: That is the most common way of doing it, and even though I haven't trawled through in.js I bet that's what they do. There are probably backup methods, but >99% of browsers do send the referer, and the domain owner can't change this setting for the user, so whatever the backup method, edge cases can be handled liberally without fear of abuse.