# How to include jquery.js in another js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I want to include jquery.js in myjs.js file. I wrote the code below for this.

```
  var theNewScript=document.createElement("script");
  theNewScript.type="text/javascript";
  theNewScript.src="http://example.com/jquery.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(theNewScript);
  $.get(myfile.php);
```

There shows an error on the 5th line that is '$ not defined'. I want to include jquery.js and then want to call $.get() function in myjs.js file. How can I do this?
Please help me

Comment: Why are you trying to use $.get() outside of a page?

Comment: I assume you meant to say `$.get("myfile.php");` instead of `$.get(myfile.php);`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if jquery has been loaded, then load it if false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Appending a script tag inside the document head programmatically does not necessarily mean that the script will be available *immediately*. You should wait for the browser to download that file, parse and execute it. Some browsers fire an `onload` event for scripts in which you can hookup your logic. But this is not a cross-browser solution. I would rather "poll" for a specific symbol to become available, like this:

```
var theNewScript = document.createElement("script");
theNewScript.type = "text/javascript";
theNewScript.src = "http://example.com/jquery.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(theNewScript);
// jQuery MAY OR MAY NOT be loaded at this stage
var waitForLoad = function () {
    if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
        $.get("myfile.php");
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(waitForLoad, 1000);
    }
};
window.setTimeout(waitForLoad, 1000);
```

Comment: Which browsers do not support onload events? It's working fine for me even in older browsers like IE 7.

Comment: I have read (but not personally confirmed) that `onload` event for script tags work in gecko, opera, etc whereas for IE you need to hook `onreadystatechange`. See http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html and http://blog.lexspoon.org/2009/12/detecting-download-failures-with-script.html

Comment: It's true that the way you call the event handler depends on the browser. I use addEventListener for modern browsers and attachEvent for old IE, works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the script doesn't load instantly, it takes some time for the script file to download into your page and execute (in case of jQuery to define $).

I would recommend you to use [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/). then you can do:

```
head.js("/path/to/jQuery.js", function() {
   $.get('myfile.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Simple answer, Dont. The jQuery file
>   is very touchy to intruders so dont
>   try. Joining other files into jQuery
>   file will often cause errors in the JS
>   console, PLUS jQuery isn't initialized
>   until the file is loaded into main
>   document.

Sorry, scratch that. Didnt quite know what you were doing.

Try this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true;
s.src = 'http://domain.com/jquery.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code before, and it worked:

```
var t=document;
var o=t.createElement('script');
o=t.standardCreateElement('script');
o.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
o.setAttribute('src','http://www.example.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.js');
t.lastChild.firstChild.appendChild(o);
```