# how to remove or hide div after page loading

Tags: javascript, html, hide

this div add to source of my web page after loading. can i use some code to hide or remove that?

```
<div style="border-right: #c6c8ca 1px solid; border-top: #c6c8ca 1px solid; left: 0px;z-index: 4000; border-left: #c6c8ca 1px solid; width: 485px; border-bottom: #c6c8ca 1px solid;position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 60px; background-color: #e9e9e9" id="divADV">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="485">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:468px" id="tdAdv">
                <iframe id="a3b67f12" name="a3b67f12" src="http://ads.adsready.com/www/delivery/afr.php?zoneid=9&amp;target=_blank" scrolling="no" style="z-index:4000; width:468px; height:60px; margin:0" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0">
                    <a href="http://ads.adsready.com/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a8fcf057" target="_blank"><img src="http://ads.adsready.com/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=9&amp;n=a8fcf057" border="0" />
                    </a>
                </iframe>
                <iframe style="width:1px; height:1px; margin:0; visibility:hidden;" src="http://persianbox.com/s.aspx?pscn=2&amp;pscr=moured.persianblog.ir&amp;psct=&amp;psep=1" scrolling="no" target="_top" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </td>
            <td style="width:16px; text-align:center; vertical-align:top"><img alt="close" src="http://persianbox.com/close.gif" id="imgClose" onclick="javascript:closeWindow();" style="cursor: hand">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd rather look for the script that adds that div than hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Jquery:

```
$("#divADV").hide()
```

or with plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById(divADV).style.display = 'none';
```

but you're better off just doing this in css:

```
#divADV{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you're saying. The code gets added dynamically?

Comment: So target it in your css (which is the simpliest option anyways) that will still apply even if the element isnt there on page load

Comment: i use all 3 ways. what is wrong with this div. i can not remove it.!

Comment: do you have a link you can post?

Comment: Hi jmore009, can you tell me technically why is it better off to do with CSS? I did for mine and it works! the JS didn't work (In my case, I'm making a website with E-commerce Woodmart)

Answer (score 2):

Here your targer div will hide after 3 second. you can set it 2 or 1 sec or set 0 to hide just after loading by changing the value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#targetDiv').delay(3000).hide();
});
```

Comment: targetDiv value must be set to?

Comment: Before do that did you add the jquery library file and check that you are calling the right element by id or class.

Comment: can you tel me how i use jquery library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496789/how-to-include-jquery-in-another-javascript-file