# how to add jquery reference in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a external java script file that should contain some validation functions. I want to add j query into my java script file, how can i do this,

I tried the following code but it seems to be not working,

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByClassName('email')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496789/how-to-include-jquery-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: instead of adding it to component, add it to head. `var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; head.appendChild(script);`

Comment: Read about RequireJS. It's file/module loader. This solution clearly resolves dependencies. It's not easy at beginning, but very helpful.

Comment: what's wrong with a <script> tag

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you should add reference to jQuery in your .html file which is going to refer the external javascript file containing validation functions.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<your java script file containing validation functions></script>
```