# JavaScript Create Table hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below code which should be taking the value of each data result and publishing it to a HTML Table. I can't figure out why the below isn't working:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    data = { d : {
        results: [
            { Title: 'Title1', Description: 'Description1', Status: 'Status1', Complete: 'Complete1' },
            { Title: 'Title2', Description: 'Description2', Status: 'Status2', Complete: 'Complete2' },
            { Title: 'Title3', Description: 'Description3', Status: 'Status3', Complete: 'Complete3' },
            { Title: 'Title4', Description: 'Description4', Status: 'Status4', Complete: 'Complete4' } ] } };

    data.d.results.push({Title: 'Title5', Description: 'Description5', Status: 'Status5', Complete: 'Complete5'});


    $(document).ready(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            item = data.d.results[i];
            str  = '<tr><td>' + item.Title + '</td><td> ' + item.Description + '</td><td>' + item.Status + '</td><td>' + item.Complete + '</td></tr>';
            $('#mytab tr').last().after(str);
       }
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table id="mytab">
    <tr>
      <td>Task Title</td> <td>Description</td> <td>Task Status</td> <td>% Complete</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [I couldn't reproduce the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/jo0bewpq/) but I had to import jquery which you might be missing.

Comment: Could you please share the browser console logs if any??

Comment: Thanks. I've amended that. Still not working though

Comment: Did you check your console for errors? It tells you what the problem is.

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Jaron787 You really don't know what the error message is telling you?

Comment: I've added the jquery import. Does anyone know why this code works in Firefox but not IE. I am not getting any console errors on IE??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4qr8Ln4e/ - This doesn't work in IE but does in Firefox & Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Extending Patrick's idea here. You can ensure JS executes after DOM is loaded by using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // execute your JavaScript code
   // that depends on DOM
});
```

Comment: I've done that but i keep getting: ReferenceError: $ is not defined in the console

Comment: In your comments section in question everyone asked you to include jQuery. Your code depends on it. Look at this question and accepted answer carefully. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496789/how-to-include-jquery-in-another-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running before your table is rendered in the DOM. Try moving your script tag from the <head> to right before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: Move the script tag from where to where?

Comment: sorry, the tags in my answer were removed. fixed it