# Jquery is not defined in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting `Jquery is not defined` in FireFox browser but works in opera, here is ex http://eef.percipio.me/index/charts.

I load jquery with

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
  var jq = document.createElement('script'); jq.type = 'text/javascript';
  // Path to jquery.js file, eg. Google hosted version
  jq.src = 'http://eef.percipio.me/themes/third_party/charts/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
}
```

and seems problem with this code, since it works if I do

```
<script src="http://eef.percipio.me/themes/third_party/charts/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: It works fine without Firebug enabled, for me. I can see the chart. But when I enable the firebug its giving error. Do you have the same issue?

Comment: yes firebug enabled but that is not solution

Comment: Works fine for me also, I don't see any errors in firebug either

Comment: Try disabling the Firebug.

Comment: Check if Firebug has 'Break on all errors' enabled

Answer (score 2):

Your link is working intermittently for me, even with firebug open. It looks like a timing issue to me, I think you need to make sure jQuery is loaded before trying to use it.

Try googling 'load jquery if not loaded' or take a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/load-jquery-only-if-not-present/) - it provides code that should help you.

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15230132/307703) is another SO question about a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Works intermittently for me, too.
Definitely a timing issue.

You could poll for the availability of jQuery:

```
function withjQuery ($) {
  // use $
} 
function pollForjQuery () {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    withjQuery(window.jQuery);
  } else {
    // checks for jQuery again in 50ms
    setTimeout(pollForjQuery, 50);
  }
}

// check for jQuery in 0, 50, 100, 150, 200ms etc.
pollForjQuery();
```

[Reference](http://support.qubitproducts.com/customer/portal/articles/1220883-how-do-i-wait-for-jquery-to-exist-on-the-page-)