# Use jQuery On Click to Change Text Inside Span

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT: I'm a fool. I didn't have jQuery loaded on my jsFiddle. I thought it automatically came loaded with a new Fiddle. Please disregard.**

Alright, I've been trying to get this to work and can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm sure it's something insanely easy and I'm just not seeing it.

I have a span with pre-populated text inside of it. I want to click the button and change the text inside of the span to something else. Then I want to click the other button and change the text again.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button id="bye">Bye</button>
    <button id="hello">Hello</button>
</div>
<div>
    <p>1: <span id="greeting">Greeting</span></p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#hello').on('click', function() {
    $('#greeting').text('Hello');
});
$('#bye').on('click', function() {
    $('#greeting').text('Bye');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yxs0pppj/6/)

Comment: you need to include jquery ... http://jsfiddle.net/yxs0pppj/7/

Comment: I think you would need to place the new text into the html:

     $("#greeting").html('Hello');

Comment: I didn't have jQuery loaded. I thought it came with a new Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

So my guess would be that you're not properly loading JQuery, I pasted this code verbatim into a rails app I had open that had JQuery loaded and it worked perfectly. So just [load JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577771/how-to-include-jquery-js-in-another-js-file) and you should be good to go

Comment: I didn't have jQuery loaded. I thought it came with a new Fiddle.

Comment: You can load it in, but the default is just pure JS