# How do i use JQuery in an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reference JQuery in an external JS file. Since the code i will be using is going to be a script, i don't have a page to load it from.

Does anyone know how to load JQuery into a JS file without the use of a html page?

Sorry if this is already answered.

Thank You.

Comment: I think this might be solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577771/how-to-include-jquery-js-in-another-js-file

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

element to any webpage which already loaded before your external js file is loaded and use jQuery object in your external file. at runtime it will find the object.

Comment: The whole point is to load it without using a web page? straight from the .js file.