# Simulate an "include_once" for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a simple page that use jQuery, so include jquery.min.js.

But I have to insert an iFrame in the same page (and no, unfortunately I can't use anything else) that include a different versione of jquery.min.js.

How can I force the browser to include only one of those two version (like an include_once in php)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not tested but at the end of your page, just before `</body>` tag, you can add this:

```
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

This checks if jQuery is available or not, if not it will add one dynamically from path specified.

Comment: @Sarfraz Is this applicable to user-defined js? not only for jquery ?