# Detect Jquery with regular javascript, if not present load it dynamcally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the code to use regular javascript to detect whether or not JQuery is present, if not, load JQuery file from google or another website

UPDATE Two Working Solutions (just copying and pasting the working code here):

From Claudio Redi

```
window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'>\x3C/script>")
```

From Rob Darwin

```
var jQueryScriptOutputted = false;
function initJQuery() {
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        if (! jQueryScriptOutputted) {
            jQueryScriptOutputted = true;
            document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js\"></scr" + "ipt>");
        }
        setTimeout("initJQuery()", 50);
    }
}
initJQuery();
```

Comment: Check this answer man http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/05/07/load-jquery-dynamically.aspx) should work.

EDIT: Code added from above link.

```
var jQueryScriptOutputted = false;
function initJQuery() {

    //if the jQuery object isn't available
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {


        if (! jQueryScriptOutputted) {
            //only output the script once..
            jQueryScriptOutputted = true;

            //output the script (load it from google api)
            document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js\"></scr" + "ipt>");
        }
        setTimeout("initJQuery()", 50);
    } else {

        $(function() {  
            //do anything that needs to be done on document.ready
        });
    }

}
initJQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked out well. I added the working code into my question.

Answer (score 17):

There are many ways, I like this most only because is the less verbose

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>  
<script>window.jQuery || 
    document.write("<script src='js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'>\x3C/script>")
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer until later. Strange. Your code works. Thanks

Comment: ugh. I clicked downvote by accident -- should have been upvote, but now it's locked-in until question is edited. sorry about that, chief.

Comment: @Michael Paulukonis: no problem. Edited answer in case you're interested in reverting your vote.

Comment: the line `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"` produces an error in Webkit which I corrected adding the protocol http.

Comment: @Francisco `//` is dynamic protocol, that means it will adopt whatever protocol is currently in use

Answer (score 11):

The *nice* way to load jQuery without using `document.write` is:

```
if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js";
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

This will cause an asynchronous load, though - so you may want to include a `.onload` handler to allow execution to wait until the load has finished.

Comment: onload doesn't seem to work always: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously