# javascript and jquery override

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I am making a small project that will let:
different websites to load my external javascript file: something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var vsid = "SA89696";
        (function() { 
            var vsjs = document.createElement('script'); vsjs.type = 'text/javascript'; vsjs.async = true; vsjs.setAttribute('defer', 'defer');
            vsjs.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'example.com/robot/robot.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(vsjs, s);
        })();
        </script>
```

now I want to use jquery in my javascript file, I dont have problem to load it by myself,
but I dont want to cause errors to the curresnt website if it already loaded jquery.

do you have any suggestions how to load jquery with no overrides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

It checks if jQuery is loaded or no..

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false)