# Load jQuery after DOM, how can I make $.ready() available to my page before jQuery is loaded?

Tags: jquery

I want to late load jQuery, but I have a small amount of inline javascript the runs on $.ready().  Since jQuery isn't loaded, these lines throw an error and never run.  Is there a way I can make $.ready() an available function, but wait on execution until jQuery is loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace ready with a function call, create a function and put that function inside $.ready()

Comment: Is this useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option for a generic way to solve this is to put your inline javascript in a function and add that function to a globally accessible array - don't call it yet.  These are essentially functions that you want to schedule for `document.ready()` when `document.ready` is available.

Then, when you do load jQuery, you set up a `document.ready()` handler that cycles through all the functions in that array and calls them.

```
// declare global at the top of your web page
var readyFns = [];

// in your inline code, add a function to the readyFns array
readyFns.push(myInlineFn);

// when your jQuery code loads, do this:
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < readyFns.length; i++) {
        readyFns[i]();
    }
});
```

If you want to use anonymous functions, you can do the middle step like this:

```
// in your inline code, add a function to the readyFns array
readyFns.push(function() {
   // put your code here
});
```

Comment: I like this, I think it'll work.  But is there a way to do this with anonymous functions like jquery does? readyFns.push(function() { }); perhaps?

Comment: @Beachhouse - I added anonymous functions to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.ready`, you could use the non-jQuery equivalent such as `window.onload`, but these tend to be somewhat incompatible with `.ready`, so I'm not sure if they will work for your needs.

Someone apparently has extracted jQuery's ready function so it can be used alone: http://code.google.com/p/domready/

Comment: +1 domready could be what I'm looking for, but the code looks like there's a bit of overhead in there to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. replace ready with a function call e.g. `example();`
2. create a function e.g. `example() { }`
3. put that function inside `(document).ready()`

Comment: Very very simple answer, but I need to check as to how this would work.  I have more than one ready block that loads before the DOM, I think this would limit me to one usage.