# Dynamically load jQuery in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm creating an external widget that uses jQuery and rather than have the user include it separately I'd like to check to see if it's loaded and load it dynamically if it's not.

Problem is I need to wait until it's loaded to execute the rest of the script, which requires event handlers that IE and FF/Chrome handle differently.

If I do this, it works fine in IE8:

```
<div id="test">
<p>This is a test.</p>
</div>

<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
    if (s.addEventListener) {
        s.addEventListener("load", runScript, false);
    } else if (s.readyState) {
        s.onreadystatechange = runScript;
    }

} else {
    runScript();
}

function runScript() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    $('#test').css('font-size', '50px');

}
</script>
```

But that doesn't work in Chrome. However if I append the script earlier, it works in Chrome but not IE:

```
<div id="test">
<p>This is a test.</p>
</div>

<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
    if (s.addEventListener) {
        s.addEventListener("load", runScript, false);
    } else if (s.readyState) {
        s.onreadystatechange = runScript;
    }

} else {
    runScript();
}

function runScript() {

    $('#test').css('font-size', '50px');

}
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to dynamically load jQuery with event handlers that works both in IE and Chrome?

**EDIT:** Changed appendChild target from test to head.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false

Comment: require.js could help you with that

Comment: You're saying "when jQuery loads, append jQuery to some random element", that does'nt work, as you can't append the script when it loads, you have to append the script first, **then** do something when it loads, and you should probably append it to the `head`, not `test`, and you don't even have an element with a `test` tag, it's a div with a `test` ID ?

Comment: @Nile I wouldn't say it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false -- that asks how to check if jQuery has been loaded. You can see I've already got that syntax in my examples, I'm asking about event handler compatibility across browsers.

Comment: @adeneo Agreed but appendChild prior to the event handler only seems to work in Chrome/FF, it does not work in IE8. Strangely only adding it after the event handler does it work in IE8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code you are appending the script in the function you are calling when it is complete!

And what element is test?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('test')[0].appendChild(s);  <-- looking for element
<div id="test">  <-- test is an id
```

The code should look like

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
    if (s.addEventListener) {
        s.addEventListener("load", runScript, false);
    } else if (s.readyState) {
        s.onreadystatechange = runScript;
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
} else {
    runScript();
}

function runScript() {
    $('#test').css('font-size', '50px');
}
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/5986T/

Comment: agreed #1 is wacky but try it in IE8 and it works, the second example, which makes more coding sense, works in Chrome but in IE while it works it also spits out a warning "Object expected" -- I assume it's executing before jQuery had been loaded? Updated my target from test to head for more clarity.

Comment: I'd also like to point out Microsoft provides this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173(v=vs.85).aspx

But that didn't work for me in IE7/8 -- could be a settings issue on my end.

Comment: I added a running example that seems fine in IE7-IE9 for me.

Comment: I tested on another config and it works. Thanks for your help.