# Explain code below, as i dont understand purpose of logical or

Tags: javascript

I am using this code in my project but don't understand the purpose of operator (`||`) in the code

```
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')
```

Comment: It's checks for a global jQuery object, and if it's not found, attempts to load it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is not undefined in the global object, then write a script element that will load jQuery from your server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional inclusion. It is merely shorthand for:

```
if ( window.jQuery ) {
} else {
    document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')
}
```

Comment: B2K and true, thanks. Both your answers opens my mind. Keep on Guys.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind situation || operator used to check, if window.jquery is true (exists) than use it, otherwise call document.write('\x3C/script>') to append it.

```
var name = newName || 'Mike';
console.log(name) // will display Mike
```

because newName variable does exist, but if I do like this

```
var newName = 'John';
var name = newName || 'Mika';
console.log(name) // will display John
```

because newName variable exists and its value is 'John'