# How to prevent loading jQuery twice

Tags: jquery

I have one jsp say jsp1 page that sometimes need to load independently and sometime I need to do AJAX call to embed that page (simply injecting a whole page with headers) inside my other jsp say jsp2. Both jsp pages have jQuery defined.

But now the issue I am facing is, if I do an AJAX call to include jsp2 inside my jsp1, jQuery is defined twice and causing all sort of issue.

Comment: What do you mean "embedded" ? Are you simply injecting a whole page with headers into another one ? Please clarify your question (hint: a question without code is almost always a bad one).

Comment: @DenysSéguret yes I am. I edited my question as well

Comment: An HTML document can only have one html tag and one body tag. Your HTML is invalid and the problem you see is only one of the many ones you'll have. You should start by fixing your structure to avoid injecting whole pages (examples of solution: have all pages inject a header part, use an existing framework).

Comment: You could opt for layout templates as shown in this tutorial: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076174/java-web-development/jsp-templates.html.  As mentioned by Denys Séguret, you can only have 1 html tag.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Is there a way that I can load only script and body tag via ajax call.

Comment: AJAX is about fetching data, not HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if jquery has been loaded, then load it if false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false)