# check jquery or javascript file is already loaded or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on JavaScript widgets. Below is my code calling widgets html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="http://localhost/widget1/widget1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost/widget1/widget2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;display: inline-block;background-color:#eee">
    <h1 align="center"><a href="#">Demo test</a></h1>
    <div id="container1" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;margin:30px"></div>
    <div id="container2" style="width: 45%; height: 300px;display: inline-block;margin:30px"></div>
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and below is my widgets1.js and widgets2.js files:

```
(function() {
  // Localize jQuery variable
  var jQuery;

  /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/

  if (typeof jQuery == undefined || typeof jQuery != '1.9.1') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("id", "jqueryLib");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function() { // For old versions of IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
        }
      };
    } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    //}
  } else {
    //The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
  }
})();
```

On html page firstly I am loading widgets1.js file and secondly I am loading widgets2.js file.I am checking http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js file if not define to load.

This file is loaded in widgets1.js file but http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js file get loaded again in widgets2.js file which i don't won't to load again.

I am checking with typeof jQuery == undefined but not validate and file get loaded two times.

Comment: `typeof jQuery` will never equal `'1.9.1'`.

Comment: and `typeof jQuery == undefined` will never be true

Comment: Why are you repeating the jQuery test in _each_ file? Just write it once

Comment: so what I do?How to validate jquery file

Comment: `if( typeof jQuery === "undefined" || typeof jQuery !== "function")`

Comment: Actually I am using js widgets file.I have different coding on each file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828267/552116 check this answer

Answer (score 0):

That's not a great way to check it, but the if-statement wouldn't work.
Try `if (!window.jQuery)`, that should work.

Also, this part:

```
jQuery = window.jQuery;
main();
```

you might want to take it outside the else-statement, because I assume you always want to execute those two lines.

A few notes:

1. When checking the `typeof` something, you should compare it with a string. So `typeof jQuery !== 'undefined'` (notice the quotes) is the correct check here.
2. `typeof jQuery === '1.9.1'` will never be true. The `typeof jQuery` would be `'function'` if it's loaded.

Comment: `$` could be something else than jQuery

Comment: Also, none of my business, but why are you assigning `jQuery = window.jQuery;` if you're not using it anywhere in that function after assigning it?

Comment: OP will never know if `$` is used for something else. From what I understand, they're developing a widget, meaning, some JS code injection in an existing page, and they precisely want to know what's already loaded in the host's DOM.

Comment: @JeremyThille might be a widget for his own site. I've removed that part to avoid confusion. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var s;
if (void 0 === window.jQuery || "1.4.2" !== window.jQuery.fn.jquery) {
var i = document.createElement("script");
i.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"), i.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), i.readyState ? i.onreadystatechange = function() {
    ("complete" == this.readyState || "loaded" == this.readyState) && e()
} : i.onload = e, (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(i)
} else s = window.jQuery, l()
}
```

Comment: I am using this but show me this in console <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="http://localhost/widget1/widget1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/widget1/widget2.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: check whether it is loaded from memory cache or disk cache?

Comment: I am clear cache but again show 1.4.2 file two times.